# Use of unresolved indetifier jsonResult

Tags: json, swift, identifier

I get this error everytime i tried to fix it. Please help

```
do {
    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        print(jsonResult)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

if (jsonResult != nil) { 
    print(jsonResult)
} else {
    // couldn't load JSON, look at error
}
```

Comment: What error? I see no error? please be more specific

Comment: Look at the `{` and the `}` `if (jsonResult != nil) {` is OUTSIDE it's declaration. Put that code where you did the `print`

Comment: if (jsonResult != nil) {   // Error is here.
    print(jsonResult)

Comment: the issue... or at least part of the issue is that you need to work with jsonResult inside the do block. otherwise it is out of scope, move it as suggested and then if you still get an issue, post more information, what is the error, what json do you have, do you actually get json data, is it of `[String:AnyObject]`? could it not be an array?

Answer (score 0):

`jsonResult` was used outside the do-try-catch statement in which it was created, so that's why you can't access it. Here is the corrected code:

```
do {
    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        print(jsonResult)
        //The following lines of code is commented out because you have used if let outside to make sure that jsonResult here is not nil.
        //So you do not need to check for it again
        //if (jsonResult != nil) { 
        //   print(jsonResult)
        //} else {
        //    // couldn't load JSON, look at error
        //}
    }

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```